# How to get actual CSS property value of an HTML element node?

Tags: javascript, html, css, getcomputedstyle

As I understand the [getComputedStyles()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method, it should return an object that allows one to access the actual CSS property values of an HTML element node.

I created this simple example with a paragraph containing a span:

```js
let span = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
let style = window.getComputedStyle(span);
span.innerText = "span background-color is " + style.getPropertyValue("background-color");
```

```html
<p style="background-color: orange">
  <span style="color: green">Empty</span>
</p>
```

The background color of the paragraph is `orange`, so the span should also have that property value, or am I mistaken? Could it be that inherited values are ignored in `getComputedStyles`? And if so, how can I get the actually visible background color for the span? Thank you.

Comment: The `<span>` itself doesn't have any background-color value, only the `<p>` does.

Comment: _“Could it be that inherited values are ignored in getComputedStyles?”_ - you are _not_ dealing with an inherited value here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background: _“Inherited: no”_

Comment: If you simply inspect said span, and look at the computed styles, you can see there is no background-color computed for it.

Comment: So the background value is never inherited? So there is no other way then to inspect all parent elements' background value?

Comment: `The background color of the paragraph is orange, so the span should also have that property value, or am I mistaken?` no it will not inherit automatically. you have to mentioned explicitly like `<span style="color: green; background-color:inherit">Empty</span>` then you will get the desired result. https://jsfiddle.net/LsdLeogq/

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai: Unfortunately I didn't find that question when researching this problem of mine. This really seems to be a duplicate and should be closed. Thank you all.

Comment: _“So the background value is never inherited?”_ - no, it isn’t, because it is simply _specified_ that way. (And for a good reason; imagine you were to use `background: rgba(0,0,0,.5)` to get a background color with an opacity - those opacity values would _multiply_ for nested elements, and that most likely won’t give you the desired effect.)

Comment: @CBroe: I see. So `getComputedStyle` is not the solution for this problem and there does not seem to be any "easy" way to get the actually visible value.

Comment: _“The background color of the paragraph is orange, so the span should also have that property value, or am I mistaken?”_ - putting a sheet of colored, semi-transparent fabric outside of your window will change what you _see_ when you look through that window - but it does not “inherit” to the window itself, and change what color glas it is ...

Answer (score 4):

It is giving you the correct result.

> span background-color is rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)

Note that the `a` in `rgba` is `0`. There is no opacity at all, the element is completely transparent.

It isn't orange, you can just see through it to the orange element behind it.

Comment: Thank you. I would still need to know the actually visible background for the span. How you actually see it. Any idea how this could be done? Do I need to inspect all parent elements and look for their background value?

Comment: you can get the parent element background color

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly — It's quite a hard problem. You could recursively search up the document tree until you find an ancestor with an explicit background-color, but that doesn't take into account background images or the fact that positioning or floats could make the element displayed behind an element one that isn't an ancestor if it at all.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Updated my answer to use pure JS to find the background color you are looking for:

```js
let span = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
let parent = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].parentElement;
let style = window.getComputedStyle(parent);
span.innerText = "span background-color is " + style.getPropertyValue("background-color");
```

```html
<p style="background-color: orange">
  <span style="color: green">Empty</span>
</p>
```

Another potential option would be updating your `style` of the span to inherit the background color of the parent, in which case your initial attempt would work:

```js
let span = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
let style = window.getComputedStyle(span);
span.innerText = "span background-color is " + style.getPropertyValue("background-color");
```

```html
<p style="background-color: orange">
  <span style="color: green; background-color: inherit">Empty</span>
</p>
```

And here is the old version using Jquery:

```js
var color = $('#getThis').closest("p").css("background-color");
$('#getThis').html('Background color is ' + color);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style="background-color: orange">
  <span id="getThis" style="color: green">Empty</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I am not allowed to use jQuery.

Comment: I updated my answer to use pure JS

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote this simple snippet to be sure that `getComputedStyle` returns only the applied style for the element, and not what is actually rendered.

```js
let style1 = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('s1'));
let style2 = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('s2'));

document.getElementById('i1').value = style1.getPropertyValue("background-color");
document.getElementById('i2').value = style2.getPropertyValue("background-color");
```

```html
<div style='background-color: cyan'>
  <span id='s1'>Span without backgound</span>
</div>

<div style='background-color: cyan'>
  <span id='s2' style='background-color: yellow'>Span with backgound</span>
</div>

<input id='i1' type='text' />
<input id='i2' type='text' />
```

But, reading the defination of `getComputedStyle` from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getcomputedstyle.asp), looks confusing, for me:

> The computed style is the style actually used in displaying the
>   element, after "stylings" from multiple sources have been applied.

Reading this, sounds like all "stylings" applied should be returned, and this is not what happens, just my opinion.

Comment: I didn't understand the down vote, could you elaborate please?

Comment: I didn't down vote, but the reason may be that this is not really an answer to the question, but rather a constructive comment.

Comment: I got, but the snippet prove that only directly applied style over the element are returned from `getComputedStyle`, so I don't think it's a simple comment, but thank you for the feedback @JennyO'Reilly

Answer (score 0):

```js
let span = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
getBackgroundColor(span);


function getBackgroundColor(ele){
  let style = window.getComputedStyle(ele);
  if(ele){
    if(ele.style.backgroundColor)
      span.innerText = "span background-color is " + style.getPropertyValue("background-color");
    else
      getBackgroundColor(ele.parentNode);
  }else
    span.innerText = "span background is transparent";
  return;
}
```

```html
<p style="background-color: orange">
  <span style="color: green">Empty</span>
</p>
```

This is done using recursion...may be this is what you want. It will keep checking its parent background-color until it finds one otherwise it will return transparent.

Answer (score 0):

if you use this

```
span.innerText = "span background-color is " + style.getPropertyValue("color");
```

then you will get the font color `rgb(0, 128, 0)` as you use in span. your syntax giving you correct answer.